# Different iterator for for loop in one code

Tags: c++, for-loop, indexing, iterator

I am creating function, which takes a vector of operators( different matrices). Operators can be provided in different ordering ( from the smallest to biggest or other way around).

I need to create for loop based on ordering

```
for(auto tr = operators.begin(); tr != operators.end() ; ++tr )
```

or

```
 for(auto tr = operators.end(); tr != operators.begin() ; --tr )
```

- content inside of loop stays same
- is there any way how to do this automatically? maybe based on some help input parameter?

Comment: In the second example, don't you mean `rbegin()` and `rend()` instead of `end()` and `begin()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can support this by having your function consume a pair of iterators (a "range") instead of a complete matrix or vector.  For example:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void print(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    for(auto tr = begin; tr != end; ++tr)
        ; // ...
}
```

This way, you can pass any sort of range in: forward, reverse, or others.  This is how much of the STL is designed.

If you use a `std::vector` for example, you'd invoke the above like so:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
print(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // forward
print(vec.rbegin(), vec.rend()); // reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

Although, technically, an `end()` iterator can often be decremented and dereferenced safely, you are relying on specific properties that not all iterators are guaranteed to have.

A number of standard containers [some introduced in C++11 do not] have both forward iterators (which iterate through elements in order) and reverse iterators (which iterate over elements in the opposite order).    The counterparts of `begin()` and `end()` are `rbegin()` and `rend()` respectively.